Movie about African American officer set on a somewhat wild west theme
It is not a new film, felt like it was made around 60~90s. It was in color.
The main plot is that an intelligent African American officer who wears a suit (attorney? detective?) comes to investigate a series of crime, despite the cynical attitudes of town people about African Americans. 
I believe as the movie goes on, the main protagonist (African American) gained respect and friendship amongst the town people. I think he went off in a train at the final scene. 
The movie itself was set on slightly underdeveloped wild west theme, but not lawless wild west such as I am Nobody sort of wild west.

Il looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Heat_of_the_Night_%28film%29 ;but it not set in the wild west.

The movie you are looking for is In the heat of the night, a 1967 movie with Sidney Poitiers as detective Virgil Tibbs. From the wiki page:

Phillip Colbert, a wealthy man from Chicago who was planning to build
  a factory in Sparta, Mississippi, is found murdered. White police
  Chief Bill Gillespie (Rod Steiger) comes under pressure to find his
  killer quickly. African-American northerner Virgil Tibbs (Sidney
  Poitier) is picked up at the train station between trains with a
  substantial amount of cash in his wallet. Gillespie, prejudiced
  against blacks, jumps to the conclusion that he has his culprit, but
  is embarrassed to learn that Tibbs is an experienced Philadelphia
  homicide detective who is simply passing through town after visiting
  his mother. After the racist treatment that he receives, Tibbs wants
  nothing more than to leave as quickly as possible, but his own chief,
  after questioning whether Tibbs himself is prejudiced, has him stay
  and help. Leslie Colbert (Lee Grant), the victim's widow, already
  frustrated by the ineptitude of the local police, is impressed by
  Tibbs's expertise when he clears another wrongly accused suspect whom
  Gillespie has arrested on circumstantial evidence. She threatens to
  stop construction on the much needed factory unless Tibbs leads the
  investigation. Unwilling to accept help, but under orders from the
  town's mayor, Gillespie talks a reluctant Tibbs into working on the
  case.

It is set in the south of USA, not in the wild west.
